# Finding $\varphi(\theta)$ such that $\sum_{n\geq 0} e^{in\theta}/(n+1) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \hat{\varphi} e^{in\theta}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have a fourier-series 
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1} e^{in\theta}
$$
How can I find a function $\varphi(\theta)$ which has the Fourier-coefficients $1/(n+1)?$ In other words, finding $\varphi$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{n+1} = \hat{\varphi}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \varphi(\theta) e^{-in\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta
$$
Is there a systematic approach, or is it all down to guess-work?

Comment: For any $a, x$ we have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1n a^{n x} =  -\log(1-a^x)$. So you can use that to sum your Fourier series and arrive at a closed form function.

Comment: The systematic approach si $c_n =  \frac{1}{n+1} \implies \sum_{n \ge 0} |c_n|^2 < \infty$ so $\sum_{n \ge 0} c_n e^{in \theta}$ converges in $L^2([0,2\pi])$.

Comment: I know comments are not for long discussions. However using the hint from Andreas I have $\varphi(\theta)=\sum_{n \geq 0} e^{in\theta}/(1+n)=−e^{-iθ} \log⁡(1−e^{i\theta})$. However, in the article, I read they use $\psi(θ)=ie^{−i\theta}(\pi−\theta)$. Has this something to do with the principal branch perhaps?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar, what is the difference between $\psi$ and $\varphi$ ?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai, that is what I am asking about. I see that $$\hat{\psi}(\theta) := \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \psi(\theta) e^{-i\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{1}{1+n}$$
So $\varphi$ and $\psi$ has the same Fourier coefficients. However, I do not know what the difference between $\psi$ and $\varphi$ is, or how to obtain $\psi$.  I plotted their imaginary and real components and they look nothing alike http://i.imgur.com/tIuJ6yB.jpg...

Comment: I am not that expert at Fourier analysis but if you are saying tha t

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1} e^{in\theta} = ie^{−i\theta}(\pi−\theta)$$

Then this is wrong. Look at $\theta = 0$.

Comment: Considering $0<\theta<2\pi.$ But it should be $$\sum_{n=-\infty,n\ne -1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}e^{in\theta}=ie^{-i\theta}(\pi-\theta).$$

Comment: That looks perfect! Any idea on how to derive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for Comments, so I write this here.

Since 
$ie^{-i\theta }(\pi-\theta )$ has Fourier coeficients
$$
c_n=\int_0^{2\pi}ie^{-i\theta }(\pi-\theta )e^{-in\theta }d\theta =\frac{1}{n+1}\quad (n\ne -1, n=0,1,\pm 2,\pm 3,...),
$$ 
$$
c_{-1}=0,
$$

and $ie^{-i\theta }(\pi-\theta )$ is continuous in $0<\theta<2\pi$, we see by the general theory of Fourier series that 
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty,n\ne -1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}e^{in\theta}=ie^{-i\theta}(\pi-\theta).
$$
But when the series $$
\sum_{n=-\infty,n\ne -1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}e^{in\theta}
$$

is given, how can we get it's closed form without using any results of Fourier series?
Since $$
\sum_{n=-\infty,n\ne -1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}e^{in\theta}
=2ie^{-i\theta }\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin n \theta }{n},
$$
the problem reduces how to sum the series $$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin n \theta }{n}
$$
by direct methods.
Perhaps residue methods is useful.

EDIT:
See, for instance, Schaum's Outlines, Complex Analysis by Spiegel and others, McGraw-Hill, Problem 7.65 at page 237. It states $$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}n\sin n\theta }{n^2+\alpha ^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sinh \alpha\theta }{\sinh \alpha \pi},\, -\pi<\theta <\pi.$$
When $\alpha =0$ we have $$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\sin n\theta }{n}=\frac{\pi}{2}\quad ( -\pi<\theta <\pi),
$$
which leads to$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin n\theta }{n}=\frac{\theta -\pi}{2}\quad (0<\theta <2\pi).
$$

Comment: For $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i n \theta}}{n}$ use [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) applied to $-\log(1-z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$ for $|z| < 1$

Answer (score 1):

All such problems become power series problems, which gives you a method to try. And it works for this case. For $|z| < 1$,
$$
    \frac{d}{dz}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}z^{n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n}=\frac{1}{1-z} \\
      \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}z^{n+1}=-\log(1-z)+C.
$$
By Abel's theorem, you may take limits to obtain the series on the boundary of the disk:
$$
     \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}e^{i(n+1)\theta}=-\log(1-e^{i\theta})+C,
\;\;\; 0 < \theta < 2\pi,
$$
assuming you use the branch of the log that is continuous on $0 < \theta < 2\pi$. The constant $C$ is determined by setting $\theta=\pi$:
$$
      \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}(-1)^{n+1}=-\log(2)+C.
$$
**Verify:** For $n > 0$, integration by parts works, but you have to use a special anti-derivative of $e^{in\theta}$ that will promote convergence at $\theta=0,2\pi$ of the evaluation terms:
\begin{align}
    \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-in\theta}\log(1-e^{i\theta})d\theta
   & = \left.\frac{e^{-in\theta}-1}{-in}\log(1-e^{i\theta})\right|_{0}^{2\pi}
   +\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-in\theta}-1}{-in}\frac{1}{1-e^{i\theta}}e^{i\theta}d\theta \\
   & = \frac{1}{-in}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-in\theta}-1}{e^{-i\theta}-1}d\theta \\
   & = \frac{1}{-in}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(e^{-i(n-1)\theta}+e^{-i(n-2)\theta}+\cdots+1)d\theta \\
   & = \frac{2\pi}{-in}
\end{align}
The coefficients for $n < 0$ are $0$ because $\log(1-z)$ is holomorphic inside the disk. For $n=0$ you must take into account $C$ as derived above, which can be ignored for $n > 0$, as it was above.